# How to obtain styled attributes anywhere outside custom view?

Tags: android, android-library, android-styles

Custom attributes are great, but all tutorials mention usage in custom views where you have AttributeSet parameter ready.

Contents of my attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="StyledDialogs">
   <attr name="sdlDialogStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="DialogStyle">
   ...
</declare-styleable>
```

I'm struggling how to access those attributes in any class outside custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours, I have figured out a way which works:

```
final TypedArray a = mContext.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(null, R.styleable.DialogStyle, R.attr.sdlDialogStyle, 0);
```

Comment: But make sure you recycle them with:'a.recycle();'

Comment: How do you get the styled value from the TypedArray?